# Unexpected page scroll up when clicking a link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I wrote an HTML page which is being viewed primarily on the iPad. Basically it's an FAQ list with a hover effect on each question. To initiate the hover effect on the ipad I had to put a dummy link like this.

```
<a href="#">The question?</a>
```

Here is the problem which is valid for every browser: When the list is so long that you have to scroll down and when you click on a link at the bottom of the page, it jumps back to the top while initiating the hover effect. I made a fiddle for demonstrating purpose:

http://jsfiddle.net/SWXHR/1/

When scrolling down and clicking on the last link, the page will jump to the top.

Question: How can I prevent the page from jumping to the top when using a dummy link?

Comment: If it is not a hyperlink, why are you filling the href property? You are probably misusing something. http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I know that I am misusing it but I don't know any touch-friendly replacement for the hover pseudo-class. Maybe someone can point me to the right direction?

Comment: The :hover can be applied to anything. If that is your only problem, you can just replace a with span. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this to your links:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">The question?</a>
```

Or if you're doing it through JQuery:

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Do not destroy other links: `$('a[href="#"]').click(...);` - this should only target hyperlinks to `#`, as per http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: Good point. I've added a blanket code to be used as required. Ive edited my answer though.

Answer (score 3):

add to the anchor tag

```
onclick="return false;"
```

This will stop it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<a href="javascript:;">The question</a>` it will do nothing (empty javascript command) and your scroll will stay in place ;)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the hover effect, you do not need to use `a` at all.

You can use spans, and substitute the CSS to target spans instead of anchors: http://jsfiddle.net/SWXHR/6/

If you want the cursor to be like the cursor for anchors, you can do that with css - `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: This won't initiate a hover effect on the iPad - I have to set an anchor.

Comment: 1. Could you explain what you mean with "hover effect on the iPad"? 2. Is there any CSS selector for it? Maybe `:focus`, or `:active`? 3. Since the iPad does not have a pointer device, how do you "hover"?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the single '#' with a double '##'.

`<a href="##">The question?</a>`