# a link should not show # in URL and scroll up when its href="#"

Tags: html, hyperlink, tags, href

How can I make a link a href="#" does not show # in URL when clicked and does not scroll up the page?

I have seen it in http://www.offroadstudios.com/creative-agency
But could not learn how they did it. 
Left menu contains a href="#" but it behaves in the way I am asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected page scroll up when clicking a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019144/unexpected-page-scroll-up-when-clicking-a-link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at that site it would appear they are using jQuery to change the visible content. To prevent a `#` from appearing in your browser bar, you can `preventDefault`:

```
$("a.myLinkClass").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //do something..
});
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SJuwL/show

Answer (score 2):

In topic author link, they used this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
    jQuery('.product-selector').each(function(i, element) {
        jQuery('.product-selector.product-' + i).click(function() {
            jQuery('a#products-top').focus();
            if (producttool == false) {
              producttool = true;
            }

            // Return false so that the page doesn't switch.
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

So, the answer on your question, is to `return false;` in onclick event.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FSou1/K3p2W/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attack a click handler to the link and prevent the default action

```
$('a').click(function(){return false});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MjyzK/show/

Answer (score -2):

To link-jump to a position in the HTML file it is possible to use a named anchor tag.

```
    <a name="here"></a>
    <a href="#here">LINK</a> <!-- jumps to the position "here" -->
```

Comment: True, but what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: If you note the named anchor directly before the link the link will not make the page scroll up.

Comment: That is the most horrible hack to a problem with an actual simple solution. And it doesn't even work: the page will scroll to the anchor, *and* the URL will change.