# Margin-top:0 starts at top of screen but keeps changing position to unspecified value

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, margin

EDIT: I've continued to look at this issue and scale down the problem in this JS Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/r7ab4/4/

Click "BUTTON - scroll down" to move the `.col` down. Then click "BUTTON - RETURN TO 0" to move `.col` back up to its original position by returning to `marginTop:0`. Except it doesn't. It ends up going to some unspecified value. Any ideas why this happens?

Original question below.

---

Please refer to this test page to see my issue:

http://joinersart.co.uk/test

If you click on the content button in the footer, the "col-aboutus" div expands from height:0 to height:100% in order to reveal the "content page". Click home in the top right to go back.

The Problem: "col-aboutus" div and all its child divs should be set at margin-top:0. This means the first div you see in the content page is "SECTION ONE". When you click the red link "NEXT - SECTION TWO", the margin-top should animate to "-200px" which makes the content slide up to the next section. The problem is once you click the red link, margin-top for "col-aboutus" div seems to go to some unspecified minus value, throwing off the "-200px" command. And it won't revert back to its correct position "margin-top:0". Even when I manually type "0" in Firebug, it's saying "margin-top:0" in the edit console but it remains at the unspecified minus value. When you click "home" to return to the start page, the code should reset back to margin-top:0 but this has no effect once the red link has been pressed. The only way to get it back is to reload the page.

Maybe I've missed something but please take a look and let me know.

Comment: The elements that animate _do_ end up with `margin-top:0`. There's some other difference

Comment: v-diff didn't reveal any difference between `content` and `content>next>home>content` except a background-color set explicitly after the cycle. Also `content>home>content` works correctly.

Comment: `#col-aboutus.col` `margin-top` is never animated. Note that this selector is redundant as `#col-aboutus` already matches only one element.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, did you say that "content>next>home>content" is working ok on your screen? PS: "content>home>content" was always fine because it appears to be clicking the "next" link that causes the issue.

Comment: Yes your correct - just seen its actually the "col-wrap" div thats animating. One interesting point - just playing around in Firebug and found if I delete "overflow:hidden" or "position:absolute" from #col-aboutus.col, the margin returns to normal and you can once again see "Section One". Problem is I need both those attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the actual problem was disguised as something it wasn't. The reason for all the `marginTop` problems is to do with the href links themselves. They seem to have this default behaviour to move their own position (and any connected divs) to the top of the screen/window when clicked. This caused the conflict. To resolve, came across this answer from another member. Just add this to your href links:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false;">The question?</a>
```

Or if you're doing it through JQuery:

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Original article here: [Unexpected page scroll up when clicking a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019144/unexpected-page-scroll-up-when-clicking-a-link)